# Adding new transaction status in netsuite

Tags: javascript, customization, status, netsuite

Iam working on netsuite & wanted to create a new status for Customer bill. The new status I wanted is "Written off". After writing off the status says "Paid in full". I want it to show "Written Off".

I found a lot of help to change the current status to another existing default status like:

Lets take an example. Below is the search filter to apply when trying to find Pending Fulfillment Sales Orders.

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('status',null,'is','SalesOrd:B')
```

and to set the status of a sales order as pending approval:

```
nlapiSubmitField('salesorder',soID,'orderstatus','A',false);
```

I also found default status list. But none which has creating a new one.

Comment: Good luck. Let us know when you've tried some things and are stuck at a certain point. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks! Will surely let you know.

Comment: where was the resource where you learned how to set and search for the various statuses? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new status for Nestuite's transactions.

One option in your case would be to create a custom field that is populated via script, workflow or formula that you use as an alternate status display. For instance unless modified by some other field it would just pass through the transaction's status value. You'd have some other field on the bill that indicates it was written off so the script that calculates the alternate status value would use that to adjust what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to define custom status would be creating a custom transaction, but, going custom transaction route can be costly affair as you would loose all standard transaction functionality - such as transform, out of the box approval feature, etc.

Comment: @bknights Thanks for your suggestions. I was doing some more research on this. Prasun as you said creating a new transaction type is indeed a very hectic option. But I am wondering if the status can be modified in scripting.  I have written a write off script for the transaction and was thinking about adding a code there.  What is your thought on this? A code like :   nlapiSubmitField('invoice', fromId, 'status','WrittenOff');

Comment: that is not going to work either. you have two approaches either create a custom transaction (long way),or as bknights said create a custom field that simulates status which we do in most solutions, and also you can post a SuiteIdea for this, I think many people will want it.