# Netsuite - Sales Order Status of item fulfilment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Pending Fulfilment is not a helpful status when looking at a sales order

Would like to know the latest status on the item fulfilment record on the sales order itself. Picked, Packed or Shipped.

This button should only show when the status of the sales order pending fulfilment.

Do i acheive this via a workflow? or customized form. We are just not sure where to start! All guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to create a new custom field and source from item fulfillment status.
See answers from here:
[Adding new transaction status in netsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659747/adding-new-transaction-status-in-netsuite)