# Does anyone know how to edit or add a Status field option, in a Purchase Order, on NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I have found ways to add fields and checkboxes, but I actually want to add a step in the Purchase Order status list.

Does anyone know any code that will do the trick?

Thanks for your help

:)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659747/adding-new-transaction-status-in-netsuite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new transaction status in netsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659747/adding-new-transaction-status-in-netsuite)